# How to make figure legends and ticks visible in JupyterLab dark theme?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab

When using JupyterLab (Version 0.32.0) dark theme, figure ticks and legends are invisible because the foreground and background colors are very close. How to make them visible?

Following are some screenshots for illustration:

Plotting code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.subplot()
plt.plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plt.plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2,
           frameon=False)
```

Output figure in the light theme:

[image]

The same output figure in the dark theme:

[image]

**Notes**:

This question has been asked multiple times in Github Issues of both [JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3922) and [Matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib/issues/25), and it has been answered by [telamonian](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3855) and [blink1073](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib/issues/25). I repost and re-answer the question here for easier lookup for the answer.

According to [issue 3855](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3855) of JupyterLab, upcoming versions may fix this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to quote [telamonian](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3855) and [blink1073](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib/issues/25)'s manual workaround here:

> `plt.style.use('dark_background')`

Following is a short demo:

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.plot(list(range(10)), list(range(10)))
```